# Passed string through segue is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass on a string from a textfield with segues but it always becomes nil

MasterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *symptomTextField;

@end
```

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DiseaseResultsViewController.h"
@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"My Symptoms Book";

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"searchFunctionSegue"])
    {
        if ([self.symptomTextField.text length])
        {
            DiseaseResultsViewController *resultsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
            resultsViewController.symptomSearchString = self.symptomTextField.text;
        }
    }

}


@end
```

DiseaseResultsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MySymptomsBookDataController;

@interface DiseaseResultsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *symptomSearchString; 

@property (nonatomic, strong) MySymptomsBookDataController *dataController;


@end
```

btw I tried this with both NSString and NSMutableString and it didn't work

I then use the symptomSearchString to create a datacontroller.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.dataController = [[MySymptomsBookDataController alloc] initDMySymptomsBookDataControllerFromJsonDataWithSymptom:symptomSearchString];
}
```

but because the string is nil it crushes. Any tips?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in `awakeFromNib` (which, by the way, is impossible)?

Comment: I copied this method from another question and I thought they had it in awakeFromNib. Where should I put it? On viewDidLoad?

Comment: You were right. It works now that I moved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with outlets on the destination view controller. Instead, add an NSString property to the destination and set that in `-prepareForSegue:`, then in `-viewDidAppear` on your destination controller use that value to populate your UI.

Comment: I did that @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *symptomSearchString; and resultsViewController.symptomSearchString = self.symptomTextField.text; (in the segue).

Answer (score 0):

Have you @synthesize the variable? In the .m